# How to make a server control work with asp:Label's AssociatedControlID property

Tags: asp.net, label

When you set the `AssociatedControlID` property on a Label control, it renders a `<label>` HTML tag with its `for` attribute set to the target control's ClientID:

```
<label id="Label" for="TextBox">Dat TextBox</label>
<input id="TextBox" name="TextBox" type="text">
```

I've made a server control that has a TextBox inside it and I would like for the label to render its `for` attribute to my control's interior TextBox.  My first thought was to point directly to my server control:

```
<asp:Label ID="AwesomeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="AwesomeControl">
    Check out my awesome control!</asp:Label>
<custom:MyControl ID="AwesomeControl" runat="Server" />
```

But that makes the `for` attribute point to the `<span>` that is rendered around the server control's contents:

```
<label id="AwesomeLabel" for="AwesomeControl">Check out my awesome control!</label>
<span id="AwesomeControl">
    <input name="AwesomeControl$ct123" type="text"></span>
```

It seems as though `AssociatedControlID` sets the `for` attribute by simply getting the target control's ClientID:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid.aspx

I don't want to go into the page's .aspx.cs to set this programmatically, because this server control is used frequently and I'd like its implementation to be as quick as possible.

Is there any other way to make Label tags render their `for` attributes to my server control's interior TextBox, either in the .aspx markup or from my server control's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your span is the element which possesses the id you are point to and your input doesn't have any ID.

Give your input element an ID and change the label so it points to that ID.

```
<asp:Label ID="AwesomeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtAwesomeControl">
    Check out my awesome control!</asp:Label>

<span id="AwesomeControl">
    <input id="txtAwesomeControl" name="AwesomeControl$ct123" type="text" />
</span>
```

Comment: Yep, I think that's what I want.  With the above naming convention, `InternalTextBox.ID = "txt" + this.ID;` in the server control's OnInit() works fine.  Visual Studio will balk at the AssociatedControlID value at design time, but it works at runtime.

Comment: Another alternative is use a naming convention for the Span instead of the TextBox, for example: `<span id="spnAwesomeControl">` then the TextBox will have the same name as the AssociatedControlID

Answer (score 5):

If your usercontrol has the ID **AwesomeControl** and the textbox inside the usercontrol has the ID **AwesomeTextbox**, you have to set the AssociatedControlID to this: **AwesomeControl:AwesomeTextbox**.

```
<asp:Label ID="AwesomeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="AwesomeControl:AwesomeTextbox">
Check out my awesome control!</asp:Label>
<custom:MyControl ID="AwesomeControl" runat="Server" />
```